# Notification-bubbles in 17.10 waiting for user-action to autohide. How to disable that function?

Tags: gnome, notification, 17.10, configure, autohide

On 17.10 gnome-notfication-bubbles are waiting for user-actions to autohide. In my case while listening music with Clementine - 17.10 needs permanent user-activity to show the latest song-notification.

How to configure the notification-bubbles that they are not waiting for user-action to hide like in Unity?

Comment: I think the only option is to disable them - See https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-notifications.html.en .

Comment: @Panther Thanks a lot for the answer. I found a workaround: In Clementine-settings there is an option to choose Clementine own notifications and not the ones from gnome. Clementine-notifications  dont't look so pretty like the gnome ones, but this is working out. :-)

Comment: I just saw that Clementine-notfications design can be configured in Clementine-settings. Looks pretty cool now. Problem solved. :-)

Comment: Post that as an answer

Comment: @Panther Well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround: In Clementine-settings there is an option to use own Clementine-notifications and not the ones from gnome. Clementine-notifications are even configurable in design in the Clementine-settings menu too.